# Process.arguments, is there a way to add a stdin config file to one of the parameters?

Tags: swift, linux, macos

I am trying to programmatically call the fdesetup (FileVault configuration tool) to add users so that their credentials can be used to unlock FileVault.  That way they will be able to have a single sign-on experience.

The corresponding terminal command is:

```
...$ sudo fdesetup add -inputplist < pathtomyconfigplist.plist
```

This works fine in the terminal.

Is it possible to pass these parameters into Process.arguments?

```
let process : Process = Process()
process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/fdesetup"
process.arguments = ["add", "-inputplist < pathtomyconfigplist.plist"]
process.launch()
```

The above code returns:

```
fdesetup: unrecognized option `-nputplist < pathtomyconfigplist.plist'
Error: Unrecognized option. (-)
```

I've also tried:

```
process.arguments = ["add", "-inputplist", "<", "pathtomyconfigplist.plist"]
```

But this returns nothing and when I call 'sudo fdesetup list', the user was not added.

So, I'm not sure if my issue is with passing the config file to stdin or if it has to do with the '-' before the option inputplist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things like `< path...` are not arguments. They're actually interpreted by your shell and handled independently from your program. To emulate what the shell does, you can always assign to `process.standardInput` a handle to that `plist` file as a `FileHandle`.

Directives like `>`, `<` and `|` as well as variable assignment like `X=y` are all shell features that affect how the command is run, and where input and output are handled.